# how to exit from a extended application in android

Tags: android

I extended Application class in android project.  I have to make some initialization and checks in OnCreate() of extended application.  I want to exit depending on checks.  But i don't know how exit from applcation.  Please help me

```
public class HAT extends Application {
   @Override
   public void onCreate() {
       // if( condition is false ) then exit
   }
```

In an activity we can exit by using finish() method

Comment: You don't exit an application. In Android, applications remain running even when you "exit" them. What happens is that they just get paused. If you want to close the application according to some check, do it in your main activity.

Comment: i want to create a list global variables according to the checks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could exit the VM:

```
System.exit(0);
```

Or you could crash your application:

```
new int[]{}[0];
```

Or you could kill your own process:

```
Process.killProcess(Process.myPid())
```

However, I don't really see why you would want to do this and there is almost certainly a better way to get the functionality you're after.

Comment: System.exit is not recommended by android team

Comment: I want normal way not by forcing

Comment: Nor by me. The others are no better. What is your use-case?